# How to hyperlink the thanks footnote using hyperref and authblk

Tags: hyperref, authblk

I would like to have the asterisk that directs to the thanks footnote hyperlinked using hyperref and authblk. In other words, I would like the asterisk, as any enumerated footnote in the text, to be blue and allow the reader to be taken to the footnote once clicking on it. The following code does the job, but it does not allow authblk to be used. Any idea is appreciated.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
%\usepackage[affil-sl]{authblk}
\usepackage[pdftex, bookmarksnumbered=true, bookmarksopen=true, bookmarksopenlevel=1, colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue, pdfstartview={FitH}]{hyperref}


\begin{document}

\title{\textbf{This is the Title}}
\author{\textbf{Myself}\hyperlink{myth}{\parbox{3pt}{\footnotemark[1]}} \\
    A University \\
    \href{mailto:myself@university.edu}{myself@university.edu}}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\let\oldthefootnote\thefootnote
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
\footnotetext[1]{\phantomsection\hypertarget{myth}{I thank X, Y and Z for valuable comments.}}
\let\thefootnote\oldthefootnote

\begin{abstract}
    This is the abstract.
\end{abstract}

This is the text\footnote{This is a hyperlinked footnote.}.

\end{document}
```