# How to add hyperlinks to author affiliation and \thanks in the footnote and order the supercripts after the author name?

Tags: hyperref, footnotes, author, affiliation

I want to make the author name section in my article exaclty as in the attached picture below:

[image]

I tried my best in the following code however I still need to:

1. Make the 'a' appears before the '*' which means makes the affiliation appear before the footnote in \thanks.
2. Make both the affiliation 'a' and the footnote '*' clickable.
   Both of these features are already in most of the articles I read. I just cannot find away to apply them to my article.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, twoside]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}



\title{This is my article title}



\author[,a]{Zeinab Elrashidy\thanks{Corresponding author. \newline {\textit{\indent ~~ Email address:} \href{mailto: zeinab@gmail.com}{zeinab@gmail.com}}}}
\affil[a]{\footnotesize{This is my affiliation XYZ university}}



\date{}


\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Thank you
Zeinab (she/her)

Comment: Alas, you can't just throw a \hyperlink and \hypertarget into the arguments (I tried).  This will require diving into the interstices of authblk.  It might be easier just to replace the whole package.

Comment: This has been asked before (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398239/how-to-hyperlink-the-thanks-footnote-using-hyperref-and-authblk?r=SearchResults&s=11|48.6838) with no answer.

Answer (score 1):

I did some research about this problem. My conclusion is that this depends on your template.

For example, the [APS template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/physics-article-template/xxgrqvcjkjdb) provides a command `\email` which meets your requirement.

However, some templates may not be able to do so. For example, I think this is already the best solution I found for IEEE template: [Footnote with same symbol for different authors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/520691/footnote-with-same-symbol-for-different-authors)